# How can I start a JavaFX application with Java 11?

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, javafx-11

Let's say I installed Oracle JDK 11 (just to make thing simpler). Then I downloaded Gluon's JavaFX 11 and unpacked in on top of JDK. Actually it doesn't matter where I unpack JavaFX (because my next aim is to make my own JRE installer based on OpenJRE).
Then I am trying to start the application:

```
c:\Program Files\MyApp>"c:\Program Files\Java\jre-11\bin\java" 
                              --module-path="c:\Program Files\Java\jre-11\lib" 
                              --add-modules=javafx.controls 
                              --add-modules=javafx.base -jar ./MyApp.jar
```

And I get this:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package jdk.internal.jrtfs in both module java.base and module jrt.fs

It I try to delete "jrs.fs" then my application crushes because some important system classes related to the class loader are missing.
What is the proper way to start JavaFX applications with Java 11?
And do I need to redistribute JavaFX every time with every application now (because now it's location must be specified in the command line that launches the application).

Comment: Does `jre-11\lib` contains the JavaFX SDK jars? Does also contain other jars that probably shouldn't be part of the module-path?. Have you tried with JavaFX SDK jars alone in one single folder? Have you checked the [getting started guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)?

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem, but you don't need to add `javafx.base` via `--add-modules` if you're already adding `javafx.controls`. The `javafx.controls` module will pull in both the `javafx.base` and `javafx.graphics` modules.

Comment: Where is the module `jrt.fs` resulting in the modulepath and what classes are missing if its not present?

Comment: Jose, yes it contains all the jars. How moving jars to the different folder could help if there will be several identical modules on the path?

Comment: nullpointer, jrt.fs in the JDK's lib folders which is in the modulepath. It's hard to say which classes are missing because it seems like there are a lot of them - class loader just doesn't work. I am going to spend some time on that trying to understand all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that when converting from Java 8 to Java 11, you can just add OpenJfx as dependencies under Maven (assuming you are using Maven).
eg

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
  <version>11.0.1-ea+1</version>
</dependency> etc
```

then you can run

```
java  -cp .;.\lib --module-path .\lib;. --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.web,javafx.swing -jar MyApp.jar
```

where Java 11 is in the Path, and all your Maven dependencies (modular or otherwise) are in the `lib` subdirectory. Module dependencies do have to be added to the `add-modules` list.

I have subsequently found that you have fewer issues if the modules are placed in a another directory, eg, the javafx modules (plus anything in the add-modules)

```
java  -cp .;.\lib --module-path .\modules;. --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.web,javafx.swing -jar MyApp.jar
```